# Is catechol (o-dihydroxybenzene) more prone to auto-oxidation than p-dihydroxybenzene or m-dihydroxybenzene?

Tags: biochemistry

Is catechol (o-dihydroxybenzene) more prone to auto-oxidation than p-dihydroxybenzene or m-dihydroxybenzene? If so, why?

Apparently, both dopamine and [caffeic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeic_acid#Chemistry) are prone to auto-oxidation. So I wonder if it's a property of o-dihydroxybenzenes in general.